# How to move a folder to under another folder in Jenkins with Python script

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a folder named `deployment`, under deployment there are two sibling folders: `folder1` and `folder2`.

i need to move folder2 with its sub contents to folder1 with python scrips, so from:

```
.../deployment/folder1/...
              /folder1/...
```

to

```
.../deployment/folder1/...
              /folder1/folder2/...
```

I know how to copy folders and jobs in Jenkins, MANUALLY, and i need to copy tens of folders to a new folder programmatically, e.g. with Python scripting.

I tried with the code:

```
import jenkins
server = jenkins.Jenkins('https://comp.com/job/deployment', username='xxxx', password='******')
server.copy_job('folder2', 'folder1/folder2')
```

The code returns:
**JenkinsException: copy[folder2 to folder1/folder2] failed, source and destination folder must be the same**

how can i have this done?

Comment: This behavior is described in the [docs](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jenkins.Jenkins.copy_job). Same for [rename_job](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jenkins.Jenkins.rename_job). You might want to try reconfiguring the job with [reconfig_job](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jenkins.Jenkins.reconfig_job) (I have not tested this, so, I can't say whether it works). Or, if you really want a copy, create a new job with [create_job](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jenkins.Jenkins.create_job)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest Python way would be using `shutil.move()`

Example:

```
SourcePath = 'C:/Users/UserName/Downloads/Test1'
DestPath = 'C:/Users/UserName/Downloads/Test2'

shutil.move(SourcePath, DestPath)
```

This would take SourcePath (including its children) and move them to the destination path.So, Test1 (and its children) are now under `C:/Users/UserName/Downloads/Test2/Test1/ChildFolderofTest1`

In my Jenkins I use this to move local builds if I want to save their state before I clean the local build.

Note: Jenkins has a python plug-in which lets you call python scripts directly from Jenkins (or even write them in the build steps). I either call the Python script directly, or write the script into the job.

Comment: In my understanding, OP has asked for how to move Jenkins jobs to another folder within the the structure of Jenkins jobs. This answer is about how to move files within the workspace.

Comment: Oh, that's not how I read his ask, I read his ask as "How to move folders in Jenkins with Python". This answer is how to move folders the Python way by a script ran in Jenkins, e.g. you can set this up to be any destination and move the folders in a post build or build step for archiving purposes. As for jobs, your comment about documentation is right, it would need to be reconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did:

The requirement:
**given:**

```
..../folder0/folder1
..../folder0/folder2/build_ear
```

**need:**

```
....folder0/folder1/folder2/build_ear
```

**Code:**

```
import jenkins
server = jenkins.Jenkins(folder0, username='xxxx', password='yyyyy')
server.create_job('folder1/folder2', jenkins.EMPTY_FOLDER_XML)

conf = server.get_job_config('folder2/build_ear')
server.create_job(/folder1/folder2/build_ear, conf)
```